# Ionic cordova media capture plugin returns error 3 for video

Tags: android, cordova, video, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have been struggling with the media capture plugin for cordova. I just wanted to test if I'm able to upload a video file. Pictures work perfectly but when I try for videos it crashes:

`navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, { duration: 8 });`

The video application opens and closes after 0 seconds of recording. The error thrown is 3 and message is "cancelled". I haven't manually cancelled it in any way and tried on multiple devices. I cannot find any information about this error and it's driving me crazy.

This is the full code (which is the standard example):

```
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
};

// start video capture
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, { duration: 8 });
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.Did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste the function that is calling `captureSuccess()`? looks like a missing argument error. You should call `getPicture`, inserting the `video` option. Look my below code using same plugin (w/ Ionic):

```
$scope.chooseVideo = function() {
    var options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(videoData){
        // do what you want with videoData
    });
}
```